# how can i change the PlaceHolder Text color in xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

im trying to change the PlaceHolder text color of Entry

in android its working fine with EntryRenderer i used the code:

Control.SetHintTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.White);

how can i do the same in ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is a *Xamarin Forms* Application , there is a easy way to set `PlaceHolder Color` for **iOS** and **Android** :

```
<Label Text="Hello, Custom Renderer!" />
<local:MyEntry Placeholder="input code" PlaceholderColor="Red"/
```

The effect :

[image]

By the way , if need to implement it in Render for **iOS** , here is the solution :

```
var text = new NSAttributedString("Hello, World", foregroundColor: UIColor.Red);
Control.AttributedPlaceholder = text;
```

You can set **AttributedPlaceholder** for `UITextField` to set color .